# Bundler GemspecError when building inside Docker container

Tags: ruby, bundle, jekyll, gemspecs

People were reporting this error and solved it by deleting a folder holding cached gems. Since I'm working inside a Docker container, this didn't seem like helpful advice for me. Indeed, the cache folder was not empty but did contain two items (I guess they are there from `gem install bundle`).

This is my (faulty) dockerfile

```
FROM nginx

RUN apt-get update -qqy && \
    apt-get install -qqy \
        build-essential \
        ruby-full \
        ruby-dev

RUN gem install bundle

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash udo

USER udo
WORKDIR /home/udo

COPY . .

RUN bundle install
RUN bundle exec -- jekyll build

USER root
RUN cp -r _site/* /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I could fix the error by replacing `RUN bundle install` with

```
RUN bundle install --path=tmp
```

at the expense of having this local `tmp` directory that I then had to add to the exclude list in the `_config.yml` for Jekyll.

I'd prefer to know what was actually going on. I suspect there's a problem with the way I use the non-root user.

Note: `bundle install --no-cache` did not help.